# Getting performance information from pages?

Tags: performance

Is there an easy way to find performance information as it relates to how long a page takes to load.  My situation is that I have a page that takes about a minute to load, it has several web parts on it and I'd like to find which ones are taking the longest to load up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One start is to use the DeveloperDashboard (if you are using SP2010). THis is a dashboard which shows processing time of the page, split by control/webpart.

It also shows all called stored procs, and much more.

Click for an image: [Developer Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxwtw.jpg)

and most important: it's standard SharePoint 2010 functionality!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using fiddler and see the result. Also I would suggest you to once review your code and see if you are following certain optimizing standards like 
Are you doing caching? It will really help you boost the performance. 
Also make sure you are not iterating a lot many times. In-case you are fetching data from a sharepoint list in your webpart then make sure you are fetching only the fields that you require and not all the fields. Use SPQuery or SPSiteDataQuery object wherever required to filter down.
Also check for memory leaks using SPDisposeCheck.

Also there is a differnce when it comes to using list.Items.Count and list.ItemCount.

Apart from using Fiddler, just do your code review once for all these points and you will observe a performance increase.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705809(v=office.14).aspx

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Geetanjali